# In order not to or in order to not

Tags: grammar

She came in quietly ____ wake the baby

I can only choose one option

a) so as not to

b) in order to not

c) in order not to

So which one is correct

Comment: A C are both correct. This is not a good multiple choice question.

Answer (score 3):

`so as not to` is correct choice as `not to` is the natural order (`I'm trying not to...`). `in order not to` is also fine in both grammar and meaning but it sounds too formal.